# How to make Django support multiple domains with one settings.py?

Tags: python, django

We want one `Django` instance to serve different domains. The only difference between them is different templates, all the rest is the same. So we tried to just modify **TEMPLATES.DIRS** in a `middleware`. But Django templates loader ignores all the changes in **TEMPLATES.DIRS** made after `settings.py` is loaded.

Is there more or less standard `Django` Way to support different **TEMPLATES.DIRS** for different domains with just one `settings.py`?

Comment: Is there any reason why this *has* to be a single instance, or could you just deploy it twice?

Comment: Those domains/websites are too close to have different settings.py. We just need to use different base.html (and a few more templates) for them.

Comment: Duplicated code at development time is a maintainability problem. Duplication at *deploy* time is *absolutely fine*. From the bird's eye view, it sounds to me like you just need two configurations for the same app. Two separate installs with different configurations is absolutely the standard way of accomplishing that. You just need a smooth (probably mostly automated) deployment process and to make sure you update them simultaneously.

Comment: The main problem of this duplication is that it requires several (one for each domain) uWSGI / Django instances running with different settings.py at the same time. Sooner or later it can lead to RAM problems.

Comment: I imagine that's only true if your machine is horribly under-powered or you have memory leaks. Trying it and bench-marking/profiling would be the only way to be sure it really does cause a problem. And even if it does require a better machine, getting better hardware should always be an option you consider because it's often cheaper than spending a lot of developer time trying to make things work with less.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem use a template variable, both `extend` and `include` support variables. Just omit the quatation marks:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

becomes

```
{% extends string_variable_with_file_name %}
```

Of cause you have to set that variable to the right filename in your context.